# Адаптивные ImageView в Android

Tags: java, android, xml

В разметке активити есть область,  в которой должны поместиться изображения(от 1 до 10). Соответственно они должны заполнять всю эту область и при большом количестве изображений уменьшаться в размере, чтобы поместиться в эту область. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можно реализовать при помощи ConstraintLayout c привязками (ширина 0dp), убирать "лишние" imageview в View.GONE...